# Auto layout issue with embed YouTube video

Tags: ios, youtube, swift2, ios-autolayout

I am having auto layout issues with an embed YouTube video.  In fact Apple have just rejected the App I have sent them on these grounds.  This is the code that I have submitted.

```
import UIKit

 class ImproveViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpepI1dtIz8"
    videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


        self.videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)

        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    })

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

This what is looks like when I run in the simulator.[image]

How can this be fixed? Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I have added the Web View constraints to the entire screen.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code look okay and I have tested it. I think you have problem in constraints.

Just add Top, Bottom, Leading and trailing constraints with constants = 0 to superview

Comment: Ok I will take a look at that when I get home. I thought I might have done this with the Web View.